# Screen reader only text is displayed in buttons that contain links with target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, css, screen-readers

```js
/** Add new-window and download classes automatically to links **/
$('a[target=_blank]').addClass('new-window');
$("a").filter(function () {
   return $(this).attr("href").match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlxs|epub|odt|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i);
}).addClass('download');

/** Links JavaScript **/
/* Check for links in document */
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
/* Create index for download links unique id*/
var downloadIndex = 0;
/* Create index for new window links unique id*/
var newWindowIndex = 0;
/* Check links on page */
for (var linkIndex = 0; linkIndex < links.length; linkIndex++) {
   /* Creating a span to wrap the screen-reader text */
   var srTxtWrapper = document.createElement("span");
   /* Add class .sr-only to screen-reader span */
   srTxtWrapper.classList.add("sr-only");

   if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("download")) {
      /* Add download attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("download", "");
      /* Add unique id to download link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "download-file-" + downloadIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying download file */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "download bestand");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link downloadt een bestand)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase downloadIndex by one for next download link */
      downloadIndex++;
   }
   else if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("new-window")) {
      /* Add target _blank attribute for link to open in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      /* Add unique id to new window link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "new-window" + newWindowIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying link opens in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "open in nieuw venster/tab");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link opent in een nieuw venster/tab)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase newWindowIndex by one for next newWindow link */
      newWindowIndex++;
   }
}
```

```css
.body--theme1 {
  --brand-color: #ffcb05;
  --brand-color-darker: #f5a61a;
  --brand-color-lighter: #fff578;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 255, 245, 120;
  --color-marker: 255, 255, 153;
}

.body--theme2 {
  --brand-color: #f16682;
  --brand-color-darker: #ee3135;
  --brand-color-lighter: #f287b7;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 242, 135, 183;
  --color-marker: 255, 102, 153;
}

.body--theme3 {
  --brand-color: #b1d249;
  --brand-color-darker: #45b97c;
  --brand-color-lighter: #d5e05b;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 213, 224, 91;
  --color-marker: 153, 255, 51;
}

.body--theme4 {
  --brand-color: #1ebcc5;
  --brand-color-darker: #4594d3;
  --brand-color-lighter: #84d0d9;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 132, 208, 217;
  --color-marker: 51, 153, 255;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #808184;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.125;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

.button:before {
  z-index: 40;
  background-color: #000
}

.button:after,
.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out
}

.button:after {
  z-index: 0
}

.button:hover:before {
  opacity: .05
}

.button:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.button span {
  margin-left: .25rem;
  margin-right: .25rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50
}

.button .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block
}

.button .icon:after {
  display: none
}

.button--small,
.inputfile+label,
.rte--small a.button {
  padding: .75rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: 400
}

.button--small .icon,
.inputfile+label .icon,
.rte--small a.button .icon {
  width: .75rem;
  height: .75rem
}

.button--small .icon--external-link,
.inputfile+label .icon--external-link,
.rte--small a.button .icon--external-link {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem
}

.button--small.button--circle,
.inputfile+label.button--circle,
.rte--small a.button--circle.button {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem
}

.button--small.button--circle .icon,
.inputfile+label.button--circle .icon,
.rte--small a.button--circle.button .icon {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem
}

.button--large {
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem
}

.button--large span {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem
}

.button--large .icon {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem
}

.button--large.button--circle {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem
}

@media (min-width:640px) {
  .button--large.button--circle {
      height: 4rem;
      width: 4rem
  }

  .button--large.button--circle .icon {
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem
  }
}

.button--xlarge {
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem
}

.button--xlarge span {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem
}

.button--xlarge .icon {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem
}

.button--xlarge.button--circle {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.875rem
}

.button--xlarge.button--circle .icon {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--xlarge.button--circle {
      height: 5rem;
      width: 5rem
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--xlarge {
      font-size: 1.875rem
  }
}

.body--theme1 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #f5a61a;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme1 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme1 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme1 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme1 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme2 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #ee3135;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme2 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme2 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme2 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme2 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme3 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #45b97c;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme3 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme3 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme3 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme3 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme4 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #4594d3;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme4 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme4 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme4 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme4 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.button--disabled,
.button.disabled,
.button[disabled] {
  background-color: #ededed;
  color: #d0d2d3;
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.button--disabled:after,
.button.disabled:after,
.button[disabled]:after {
  display: none
}

.button--disabled:hover,
.button.disabled:hover,
.button[disabled]:hover {
  color: #d0d2d3;
  box-shadow: none
}

.button--disabled:hover:after,
.button--disabled:hover:before,
.button.disabled:hover:after,
.button.disabled:hover:before,
.button[disabled]:hover:after,
.button[disabled]:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--high-contrast .button--disabled,
.body--high-contrast .button.disabled,
.body--high-contrast .button[disabled] {
  background-color: #757575
}

.body--high-contrast .button--disabled:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button.disabled:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button[disabled]:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.button[target=_blank].button--small:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow),
.inputfile+label.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow),
.rte--small a.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow) {
  padding-left: 2rem
}

.button[target=_blank].button--small:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before,
.inputfile+label.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before,
.rte--small a.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  height: .75rem;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.button--arrow,
.button--download,
.button[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-block
}

.button--arrow:hover,
.button--download:hover,
.button[target=_blank]:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea
}

.button--arrow:hover:before,
.button--download:hover:before,
.button[target=_blank]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1
}

.body--theme1 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme1 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme1 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #dd9617
}

.body--theme2 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme2 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme2 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #d72c30
}

.body--theme3 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme3 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme3 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #3fa670
}

.body--theme4 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme4 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme4 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #3e85bf
}

.body--high-contrast .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #58595b
}

.button--arrow.button--color:hover:before,
.button--download.button--color:hover:before,
.button[target=_blank].button--color:hover:before {
  opacity: 1
}

.button--arrow:before,
.button--download:before,
.button[target=_blank]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  position: static;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 576 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M448 279.196V464c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V112c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48h248a24 24 0 0116.97 7.029l16 16C344.09 102.149 333.382 128 312 128H64v320h320V295.196c0-6.365 2.529-12.47 7.029-16.971l16-16C422.148 247.106 448 257.814 448 279.196zM576 37.333C576 16.715 559.285 0 538.667 0H380c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28v17.885c0 15.766 13.011 28.424 28.772 27.989l67.203-1.906L199.09 319.09c-9.429 9.363-9.457 24.605-.061 34.001l23.879 23.879c9.396 9.396 24.639 9.369 34.001-.06l247.122-248.885-1.906 67.203c-.434 15.76 12.224 28.772 27.99 28.772H548c15.464 0 28-12.536 28-28V37.333z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  content: ""
}

.button--download:before {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M216 0h80c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v168h87.7c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L269.7 378.3c-7.5 7.5-19.8 7.5-27.3 0L90.1 226.1c-12.6-12.6-3.7-34.1 14.1-34.1H192V24c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zm296 376v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24V376c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h146.7l49 49c20.1 20.1 52.5 20.1 72.6 0l49-49H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20zm64 0c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.button--arrow,
.button--readmore {
  padding-right: 2.5rem
}

.button--arrow:before,
.button--readmore:before {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  margin-right: .75rem !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.body--theme1 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme1 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f5a61a' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme2 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme2 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23ee3135' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme3 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme3 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%2345b97c' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme4 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme4 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%234594d3' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--high-contrast .button--arrow:before,
.body--high-contrast .button--readmore:before,
.button--color.button--arrow:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.button--entries {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.button--entries[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-flex
}

.button--entries[target=_blank]:before {
  display: none
}

.button--entries span {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.button--entries.button--icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  text-align: left
}

.button--entries.button--icon:before {
  display: none
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center
  }
}

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon {
      position: relative
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span.icon {
      position: static
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span.icon:before {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 100% 100%;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 23 56' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M23 0v56H0z' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      content: "";
      margin-right: -1px;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
      transform: translateX(10px);
      transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .15s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out
  }

  .body--high-contrast .button--entries.button--icon span.icon:before {
      display: none
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
      padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
      padding-right: 1.5rem !important
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon:hover:after {
      display: none
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon:hover span.icon:before {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.button--entries.button--icon .icon {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.button--entries.button--icon .icon img {
  height: 2rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon .icon {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5rem;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-top: .5rem;
      margin-bottom: .75rem
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon .icon img {
      height: 2.5rem
  }
}

.button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: .25rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      max-width: 20rem
  }
}

.button--circle[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-flex
}

.button--circle[target=_blank]:before {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Buttons</title>
  </head>
  <body class="body--theme1">
    <div class="flex w-full mb-2">
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span>Text only</span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span>Text + Icon</span><span class="icon fill-current  icon--arrow-right"><svg
                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" aria-hidden="true"
                                 focusable="false">
                                 <path 
                                    d="M218.101 38.101L198.302 57.9c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971L353.432 230H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v28c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h341.432l-155.13 155.13c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l19.799 19.799c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.971 0l209.414-209.414c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L235.071 38.101c-4.686-4.687-12.284-4.687-16.97 0z">
                                 </path>
                              </svg></span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span class="icon fill-current  icon--arrow-left"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                 viewBox="0 0 448 512" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
                                 <path 
                                    d="M229.9 473.899l19.799-19.799c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L94.569 282H436c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-28c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12H94.569l155.13-155.13c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L229.9 38.101c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.971 0L3.515 247.515c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971L212.929 473.9c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.971-.001z">
                                 </path>
                              </svg></span><span>Icon + Text</span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"
                        class="button button--color">Button New Page</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="#" class="button button--color button--download">Button Download</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="#" class="button button--color button--arrow">Button Pijl</a>       
                  </div>
               </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my project I have some links that open in new tabs/windows by using the attribute `target="_blank"` I use JavaScript to both create a tooltip and screen reader only text, which show and/or tell that those links open in new tabs/windows. The script in combination with CSS also adds Font Awesome icons after the link to show if the link open in a new window or downloads a file. I could prevent this happening in buttons by using the :not() CSS pseudo-class, as shown here:

```
a.new-window:not(.button)::after,
a.download:not(.button)::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: 0.35rem
}

a.new-window:not(.button)::after {
  content: "\f08e"
}

a.download:not(.button)::after {
  content: "\f019"
}
```

That works fine for standard links.
However, when I use buttons that contain these links that open in new tabs/windows the screen reader only text (in Dutch!) is also displayed in the buttons, as shown in the following image. [image: Button displaying screen reader only text]
I tried to visually hide the screen reader only text:

```
.sr-only {
  position:absolute;
  left:-10000px;
  top:auto;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

This also worked well, but where the text was displayed now only shows empty button space, as shown in the following image.[image: Button where screen reader only text is hidden, but shows empty button space]

Is there another solution in which the screen reader only text is not displayed in the button and also not leaves a lot of empty button space?

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] when asking questions like this. I tried to get your JS to do it's job in a jsfiddle, but something appears to be missing. (Questionable whether we need to see the JS here in the first place, an example of the HTML/DOM structure this creates copy&pasted from the browser dev tools, would probably be enough already.)

Comment: @CBroe I added a code snippet, but it also shows some errors, which I can not remove, at the monent.

Comment: Inspecting the elements clearly shows that the absolute positioning from your `.sr-only` rule, gets overwritten with relative, by a rule with the selector `.button span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `.button span` style overwrites the `.sr-only` class and set the position to relative. Removing this fixes this.

```js
/** Add new-window and download classes automatically to links **/
$('a[target=_blank]').addClass('new-window');
$("a").filter(function () {
   return $(this).attr("href").match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlxs|epub|odt|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i);
}).addClass('download');

/** Links JavaScript **/
/* Check for links in document */
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
/* Create index for download links unique id*/
var downloadIndex = 0;
/* Create index for new window links unique id*/
var newWindowIndex = 0;
/* Check links on page */
for (var linkIndex = 0; linkIndex < links.length; linkIndex++) {
   /* Creating a span to wrap the screen-reader text */
   var srTxtWrapper = document.createElement("span");
   /* Add class .sr-only to screen-reader span */
   srTxtWrapper.classList.add("sr-only");

   if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("download")) {
      /* Add download attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("download", "");
      /* Add unique id to download link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "download-file-" + downloadIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying download file */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "download bestand");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link downloadt een bestand)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase downloadIndex by one for next download link */
      downloadIndex++;
   }
   else if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("new-window")) {
      /* Add target _blank attribute for link to open in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      /* Add unique id to new window link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "new-window" + newWindowIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying link opens in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "open in nieuw venster/tab");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link opent in een nieuw venster/tab)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase newWindowIndex by one for next newWindow link */
      newWindowIndex++;
   }
}
```

```css
.body--theme1 {
  --brand-color: #ffcb05;
  --brand-color-darker: #f5a61a;
  --brand-color-lighter: #fff578;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 255, 245, 120;
  --color-marker: 255, 255, 153;
}

.body--theme2 {
  --brand-color: #f16682;
  --brand-color-darker: #ee3135;
  --brand-color-lighter: #f287b7;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 242, 135, 183;
  --color-marker: 255, 102, 153;
}

.body--theme3 {
  --brand-color: #b1d249;
  --brand-color-darker: #45b97c;
  --brand-color-lighter: #d5e05b;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 213, 224, 91;
  --color-marker: 153, 255, 51;
}

.body--theme4 {
  --brand-color: #1ebcc5;
  --brand-color-darker: #4594d3;
  --brand-color-lighter: #84d0d9;
  --brand-color-lighter-rgba: 132, 208, 217;
  --color-marker: 51, 153, 255;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #808184;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.125;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

.button:before {
  z-index: 40;
  background-color: #000
}

.button:after,
.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out
}

.button:after {
  z-index: 0
}

.button:hover:before {
  opacity: .05
}

.button:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.button span {
  margin-left: .25rem;
  margin-right: .25rem;
  z-index: 50
}

.button .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block
}

.button .icon:after {
  display: none
}

.button--small,
.inputfile+label,
.rte--small a.button {
  padding: .75rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: 400
}

.button--small .icon,
.inputfile+label .icon,
.rte--small a.button .icon {
  width: .75rem;
  height: .75rem
}

.button--small .icon--external-link,
.inputfile+label .icon--external-link,
.rte--small a.button .icon--external-link {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem
}

.button--small.button--circle,
.inputfile+label.button--circle,
.rte--small a.button--circle.button {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem
}

.button--small.button--circle .icon,
.inputfile+label.button--circle .icon,
.rte--small a.button--circle.button .icon {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem
}

.button--large {
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem
}

.button--large span {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem
}

.button--large .icon {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem
}

.button--large.button--circle {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem
}

@media (min-width:640px) {
  .button--large.button--circle {
      height: 4rem;
      width: 4rem
  }

  .button--large.button--circle .icon {
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem
  }
}

.button--xlarge {
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem
}

.button--xlarge span {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem
}

.button--xlarge .icon {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem
}

.button--xlarge.button--circle {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.875rem
}

.button--xlarge.button--circle .icon {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--xlarge.button--circle {
      height: 5rem;
      width: 5rem
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--xlarge {
      font-size: 1.875rem
  }
}

.body--theme1 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #f5a61a;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme1 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme1 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme1 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme1 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme2 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #ee3135;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme2 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme2 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme2 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme2 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme3 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #45b97c;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme3 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme3 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme3 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme3 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--theme4 .button--color,
.button--name {
  background-color: #4594d3;
  color: #fff
}

.body--theme4 .button--color:hover:before,
.button--name:hover:before {
  opacity: .1
}

.body--theme4 .button--color:hover:after,
.button--name:hover:after {
  opacity: .5
}

.body--theme4 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:after,
.body--theme4 .button--color-remove-hover:hover:before,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:after,
.button--name-remove-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.button--disabled,
.button.disabled,
.button[disabled] {
  background-color: #ededed;
  color: #d0d2d3;
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.button--disabled:after,
.button.disabled:after,
.button[disabled]:after {
  display: none
}

.button--disabled:hover,
.button.disabled:hover,
.button[disabled]:hover {
  color: #d0d2d3;
  box-shadow: none
}

.button--disabled:hover:after,
.button--disabled:hover:before,
.button.disabled:hover:after,
.button.disabled:hover:before,
.button[disabled]:hover:after,
.button[disabled]:hover:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.body--high-contrast .button--disabled,
.body--high-contrast .button.disabled,
.body--high-contrast .button[disabled] {
  background-color: #757575
}

.body--high-contrast .button--disabled:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button.disabled:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button[disabled]:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.button[target=_blank].button--small:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow),
.inputfile+label.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow),
.rte--small a.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow) {
  padding-left: 2rem
}

.button[target=_blank].button--small:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before,
.inputfile+label.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before,
.rte--small a.button[target=_blank]:not(.button--download):not(.button--arrow):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  height: .75rem;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.button--arrow,
.button--download,
.button[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-block
}

.button--arrow:hover,
.button--download:hover,
.button[target=_blank]:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea
}

.button--arrow:hover:before,
.button--download:hover:before,
.button[target=_blank]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1
}

.body--theme1 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme1 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme1 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #dd9617
}

.body--theme2 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme2 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme2 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #d72c30
}

.body--theme3 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme3 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme3 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #3fa670
}

.body--theme4 .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--theme4 .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--theme4 .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #3e85bf
}

.body--high-contrast .button--arrow.button--color:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button--download.button--color:hover,
.body--high-contrast .button[target=_blank].button--color:hover {
  background-color: #58595b
}

.button--arrow.button--color:hover:before,
.button--download.button--color:hover:before,
.button[target=_blank].button--color:hover:before {
  opacity: 1
}

.button--arrow:before,
.button--download:before,
.button[target=_blank]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  position: static;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 576 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M448 279.196V464c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V112c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48h248a24 24 0 0116.97 7.029l16 16C344.09 102.149 333.382 128 312 128H64v320h320V295.196c0-6.365 2.529-12.47 7.029-16.971l16-16C422.148 247.106 448 257.814 448 279.196zM576 37.333C576 16.715 559.285 0 538.667 0H380c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28v17.885c0 15.766 13.011 28.424 28.772 27.989l67.203-1.906L199.09 319.09c-9.429 9.363-9.457 24.605-.061 34.001l23.879 23.879c9.396 9.396 24.639 9.369 34.001-.06l247.122-248.885-1.906 67.203c-.434 15.76 12.224 28.772 27.99 28.772H548c15.464 0 28-12.536 28-28V37.333z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  content: ""
}

.button--download:before {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M216 0h80c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v168h87.7c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L269.7 378.3c-7.5 7.5-19.8 7.5-27.3 0L90.1 226.1c-12.6-12.6-3.7-34.1 14.1-34.1H192V24c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zm296 376v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24V376c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h146.7l49 49c20.1 20.1 52.5 20.1 72.6 0l49-49H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20zm64 0c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.button--arrow,
.button--readmore {
  padding-right: 2.5rem
}

.button--arrow:before,
.button--readmore:before {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  margin-right: .75rem !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.body--theme1 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme1 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f5a61a' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme2 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme2 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23ee3135' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme3 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme3 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%2345b97c' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--theme4 .button--arrow:before,
.body--theme4 .button--readmore:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%234594d3' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.body--high-contrast .button--arrow:before,
.body--high-contrast .button--readmore:before,
.button--color.button--arrow:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 448 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M190.5 66.9l22.2-22.2c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L441 239c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L246.6 467.3c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.2-22.2c-9.5-9.5-9.3-25 .4-34.3L311.4 296H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24v-32c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h287.4L190.9 101.2c-9.8-9.3-10-24.8-.4-34.3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important
}

.button--entries {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.button--entries[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-flex
}

.button--entries[target=_blank]:before {
  display: none
}

.button--entries span {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.button--entries.button--icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  text-align: left
}

.button--entries.button--icon:before {
  display: none
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center
  }
}

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon {
      position: relative
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span.icon {
      position: static
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span.icon:before {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 100% 100%;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 23 56' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M23 0v56H0z' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      content: "";
      margin-right: -1px;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
      transform: translateX(10px);
      transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .15s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out
  }

  .body--high-contrast .button--entries.button--icon span.icon:before {
      display: none
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
      padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
      padding-right: 1.5rem !important
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon:hover:after {
      display: none
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon:hover span.icon:before {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.button--entries.button--icon .icon {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.button--entries.button--icon .icon img {
  height: 2rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon .icon {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5rem;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-top: .5rem;
      margin-bottom: .75rem
  }

  .button--entries.button--icon .icon img {
      height: 2.5rem
  }
}

.button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .button--entries.button--icon span:not(.icon) {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: .25rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      max-width: 20rem
  }
}

.button--circle[target=_blank] {
  display: inline-flex
}

.button--circle[target=_blank]:before {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Buttons</title>
  </head>
  <body class="body--theme1">
    <div class="flex w-full mb-2">
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span>Text only</span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span>Text + Icon</span><span class="icon fill-current  icon--arrow-right"><svg
                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" aria-hidden="true"
                                 focusable="false">
                                 <path 
                                    d="M218.101 38.101L198.302 57.9c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971L353.432 230H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v28c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h341.432l-155.13 155.13c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l19.799 19.799c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.971 0l209.414-209.414c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L235.071 38.101c-4.686-4.687-12.284-4.687-16.97 0z">
                                 </path>
                              </svg></span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                     <div class="flex-initial mr-4 my-2">

                        <a id="" href="#" class="button button--color">

                           <span class="icon fill-current  icon--arrow-left"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                 viewBox="0 0 448 512" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
                                 <path 
                                    d="M229.9 473.899l19.799-19.799c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L94.569 282H436c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-28c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12H94.569l155.13-155.13c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L229.9 38.101c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.971 0L3.515 247.515c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971L212.929 473.9c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.971-.001z">
                                 </path>
                              </svg></span><span>Icon + Text</span>
                        </a>


                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"
                        class="button button--color">Button New Page</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="#" class="button button--color button--download">Button Download</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-full mb-2 my-2">
                     <a href="#" class="button button--color button--arrow">Button Pijl</a>       
                  </div>
               </div>
  </body>
</html>
```